# JPA @OneToMany : foreign key is null

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

I need help to define correctly a @OneToMany JPA annotation.  Tried different ways but still get error/issues like the foreign key (visitor_revision_id) is null in the visitorCharacteristic table.

I would like to join the 2 tables with the "visitor_revision_id"

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
@ToString
public class Visitor {
    @Id
    @Column(name="visitor_revision_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    String visitorCode;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "visitor")
    List<VisitorCharacteristic> visitorCharacteristicList;
}

@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
@ToString
class VisitorCharacteristic {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "visitor_revision_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false) //fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade =  CascadeType.ALL)
    Visitor visitor;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String attributeCode;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String attributeValue;    
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you provide a unit test example showing the failure?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! I didn't know that I had to manually set the VisitorCharacteristic#visitor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JPA will not set `VisitorCharacteristic#visitor` field for you, you have to do it manually. If you have some method for adding subsequent `VisitorCharacteristic`s, you should add the code for setting visitor in characteristic as well:

```
public void addVisitorCharacteristic(VisitorCharacteristic visitorCharacteristic) {
    if (visitorCharacteristicList == null) {
        visitorCharacteristicList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    visitorCharacteristic.visitor = this;
    visitorCharacteristicList.add(visitorCharacteristic);
}
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/MaciejDobrowolski/ce2e01a9f8b039266731d920bbcdfcc0) you can find a Gist with your code which works well - look at the line 79.

Answer (score 1):

Without a test case showing the failure its difficult to tell.

Here are some things you can try:

1. add `, nullable = false` to the join column annotation on `VisitorCharacteristic`
2. set the relationship in both directions

   `Visitor v = new Visitor();
   VisitorCharacteristic vc = new VisitorCharacteristic();
   v.setVisitorCharacteristicList(Arrays.asList(vc));
   vc.setVisitor(v);`

Comment: not working....

Comment: I think this works only when VisitorCharacteristic does not have a Visitor attribute. As that's what I wanted, one point from me.

Answer (score 1):

class Visitor

```
public class Visitor {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "visitor_revision_id")
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Column
    String visitorCode;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "visitor_revision_id", referencedColumnName = "visitor_revision_id")
    List<VisitorCharacteristic> visitorCharacteristicList;
}
```

VisitorCharacteristic

```
public class VisitorCharacteristic {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Column
    String attributeCode;
    @Column
    String attributeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by annotating as follows:

`@RepositoryRestResource(export = false)` on `VisitorCharacteristicRepository`

and creating your own custom controller For `VisitorCharacteristic`.

For more understanding you can see - https://youtu.be/FRvtVf9sVjs

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 tables :
Users and Wallets  I wanted to link these two tables with FK relationship and I was using hibernate with Repository pattern.

When I was doing following I was getting :
ERROR: null value in column "user_id" of relation "wallet" violates not-null constraint

Details : [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [user_id" of relation "wallet]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]

```
    Wallet wallet = new Wallet();
    wallet.setAccountsSet(Set.of("creditAccount", "debitAccount"));

    Users user = UsersMapper
            .dtoToEntity(usersDto       
            .setWalletDtoSet(
              Set.of(WalletMapper.entityToDto(wallet)))
            );
   
    this.usersRepository.save(user);
```

Root Cause : There was not null constraint on the FK in Wallet table. Removing not-null constraint resolved the issue of constraint violation - user_id is null

Tables :

```
CREATE TABLE public.users (
id varchar NOT NULL,
is_active bool NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
created_by varchar NOT NULL,
creation_timestamp timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
updated_by varchar NULL,
update_timestamp timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
CONSTRAINT users_uuid_pk PRIMARY KEY (uuid)
);


CREATE TABLE public.wallet (
wallet_id int4 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
user_id varchar NULL,
CONSTRAINT wallet_wallet_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (wallet_id),
CONSTRAINT wallet_user_uuid_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_uuid) REFERENCES public.users(uuid)
);
```