# Jpa @onetomany can't generate foreign key for the inverse side

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Movie class has a list of his sessions and I want to persist simultaneously the movie and his sessions stored in the list.

So here is my code

```
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "movie_id")
    private int movieId;

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Session> sessionList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
public class Session {
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "session_id")
    private int sessionId;

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")
    private Movie movie;

}
```

test code

```
public void testAddMovie(){
        Session session1 = new Session();
        session1.setDay("Monday");


        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setTitle("hello");
        movie.getSessionList().add(session1);

        movieDao.addMovie(movie);
    }
```

sql generated by hibernate

```
   insert 
   into
           movies
            (actors, .... ,title) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ..., ?, ?, ?, ?)

  insert 
  into
            sessions
            (day, movie_id, time) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?)
```

Hibernate throws no exception, and both movie and session are successfully persisted but the
foreign key 'movie_id' in the table session show always null.

so what's the problem? And when I only used @onetomany without @manytoone the same test works fine the foreign key is successfully added.

Answer (score 0):

In Session entity, change de movie propertie to:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_session_movie."))
private Movie movie;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I missed some part of the code. Here is the link to explain the reason.
[JPA @OneToMany : foreign key is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977239/jpa-onetomany-foreign-key-is-null)